# Create identicon of a DNA sequence

Tags: visualization, egf

How can I create an [identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) (a visual representation) of a DNA sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sequenticon](https://github.com/Edinburgh-Genome-Foundry/sequenticon) is a Python library for generating identicons for DNA sequences. For instance, the sequence `ATGGTGCA` gets converted into the following icon:

[image: ATGGTGCA]

A web interface is also provided at EGF CUBA (Collection of Useful Biological Apps): [Render Sequenticons](https://cuba.genomefoundry.org/render-sequenticons)

*Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of Sequenticon*

Comment: Hey Peter, like WOW, what a post! and what an answer ... thank you. In case anyone is wondering this has REAL potential. Personally I think there needs to be further development, but like its VERY cool.